# Search for specific information in response().read()

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize, httpresponse

I'm trying to find out if form was submitted correctly using `Mechanize Python library`. 
How can I search for specific text in returned website? For example I want to check if website contain text: **"Submitted correctly"** and then break the loop (or do anything else...)

**This is part of my code:**

```
try:
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['email'] = MAIL
br.submit()

print br.response().read()
except HTTPError, e:
    print "Error: ", e.code
finally:
    test= 0.0
    test1= []
```

Comment: There is a string method called `.find()` which may help with your immediate goal. For anything more advance, however, you will want to use a full-fledged HTML-parsing tool like BeautifulSoup or lxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can use `if 'foo' in string_variable: print('yes')`